# Mongodb aggregation without group accumulator operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to aggregation group without accumulator operators?

This is my script:

```js
var filterData = {SAL04: 0, SAL05: 0, SAL06: 0, SAL07: 0, SAL08: 0}
var groupData = {AKUN: "$AKUN", KELUNIT: "$KELUNIT", NMUNIT: "$NMUNIT"}

isGroupSingle.aggregate([
  {$match: {$and: [filterData]}},
  {$group: {_id: groupData}}
]).toArray(function (error, data) {
  if (error)
    response.json(error);
  else if (data)
    response.json(data);
});
```

And this is my response:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "AKUN": "31218",
            "KELUNIT": "312181706",
            "NMUNIT": "PBB CABANG PRINGSEWU"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "AKUN": "31218",
            "KELUNIT": "312181703",
            "NMUNIT": "PBB LAMPUNG"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "AKUN": "31218",
            "KELUNIT": "312181503",
            "NMUNIT": "PBB CABANG KARAWANG"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm wanna like this: `[{"AKUN": "47377", "KELUNIT": "83773873", "NMUNIT": "PBB BLA BLA"}, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation stage called [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) is exactly what you need. As the name suggests, it replaces the whole document with a specified document (a single field in your case):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // ...
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$_id'}}
])
```

Note: It's available in MongoDB 3.4 and newer.